# Scrapy crawl and downloading particular Type files

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm very new to this, My Task is : Let me tell what exactly I need, I want to scrapy to search and download for some contract which TYPE is EX-10.1, EX-10.2, etc., upto EX-10.99. Contracts available in .htm format and txt format. 
1. How to scrap the links and download.
2. How to filter the file types and download.
Scrapy wants to go through this path and download, Path : url->Enter into  each CIK links -> search and Download the EX-10 Type files.

My code

```
import urlparse

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
class legco(BaseSpider):
name = "sec_gov"

allowed_domains = ["www.sec.gov", "search.usa.gov", "secsearch.sec.gov"]
start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany"]


#extract search results
def parse(self, response): 
for link in response.xpath('//div[@id="seriesDiv"]//table[@class="tableFile2"]/a/@href').extract():
    req = Request(url = link, callback = self.parse_page)
    yield req

def parse(self, response):
base_url = 'http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar'
for a in response.xpath('//a[@href]/@href'):
    link = a.extract()
    if link.endswith('.htm'):
        link = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)
        yield Request(link, callback = self.save_pdf)

def save_pdf(self, response):
path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.body)
```

What changes I have to do? Can anyone help me with this Issue please. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: What behaviour you are seeing from the above code ? As in, is it erring out ? If so please add the error to your question. Or is it working fine but you are getting an empty file ? Thank you and welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Biswanath, In this while am running this code, It downloading the current page .hmt files, but i want scrapy to goto next page and download the files.

Comment: Interesting, the above posted code does not even work for me. May be you posted the wrong set of code ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I have updated the code, Can you try now. Its downloading for this current page, Once I change the URL(previous & over all search page) its not getting to this page. can you help me with this.?

Comment: Was there a reasone parse_page there previously. As currently your code is trying to download all htm files instead of files reachable by using the documentbutton ?

Comment: Let me tell what exactly I need, I want to scrapy to search and download for some contract which TYPE is EX-10.1, EX-10.2, etc., upto EX-10.99. Contracts available in .htm format and txt format. I have edited the Start URL. How to scrap the links and download. and How to filter the file types and download,

Comment: Hello Biswanath, I have updated the code, can you pls check it now ? Code was executing successfully but nothing happens.